# Unable to detect if the command has ended in a batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file to automate the process of SASS compilation to CSS and further split the created CSS using BLESS using `sass` gem of ruby and `bless` repository of nodejs.

**Approach:**

I have created 3 batch files,

1. To compile SASS to CSS
2. To split created CSS USING BLESS
3. A master file to run both one after the other.

**Problem:**

The batch file 1 (SASS to CSS) never ends. Even when the execution of `sass` command is over the batch process does not ends. I tried using `EXIT` command after `sass` command but still no luck.

**Code**

Batch File 1 -- SASS to CSS

```
D:
CD D:\webapp\scss_modules
sass app.scss ..\styles\themes\app.css
EXIT
```

Batch File 2 -- Split CSS using BLESS

```
D:
CD D:\styles\themes
blessc app.css -f
EXIT
```

Batch File 3 -- Master File to run the above 2 Files

```
START /W BATCH1.BAT
START /W BATCH2.BAT
```

Comment: Unless you're using Windows 3.11 there's no MS-DOS involved here. It's also worth noting that a simple `Rakefile` would allow you do to all of this and more.

Comment: `Rakefile` won't solve my purpose. I specifically need a batch file for the same.

Comment: If you're sure. In my experience `rake` can do everything a simple batch file can do and more.

Comment: I agree on that part but I specially need to do this task using a batch file.

Comment: I'd use `call` to run batch files from another one, unless I really need them to operate in separate windows or in parallel; `exit` needs to be replaced by `exit /B` or `goto :EOF` then...

Comment: I want the Second One to run after first one not concurrently.

Comment: Are `sass` and `blessc` batch files too? if so, place `call` in front of them...

Comment: Tried using `call` it does not recognizes my second batch file and throws an error and when using `cmd` it runs both of them concurrently.

Comment: No! `blessc` and `sass` are commands. @aschipfl